# Strange timings on missing values in Python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, nan, missing-data, timing

I have a long 1-d numpy array with some 10% missing values. I want to change its missing values (np.nan) to other values repeatedly. I know of two ways to do this:

`data[np.isnan(data)] = 0` or the function 
`np.copyto(data, 0, where=np.isnan(data))`

Sometimes I want to put zeros there, other times I want to restore the `nan`s.
I thought that recomputing the `np.isnan` function repeatedly would be slow, and it would be better to save the locations of the nans. Some of the timing results of the code below are counter-intuitive.

I ran the following:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
print(f'numpy version {np.__version__}')
data = np.random.random(100000)
data[data<0.1] = 0
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit missing = np.isnan(data)
%timeit wheremiss = np.where(np.isnan(data))
missing = np.isnan(data)
wheremiss = np.where(np.isnan(data))
print("Use missing list store 0")
%timeit data[missing] = 0
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit data[wheremiss] = 0
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit np.copyto(data, 0, where=missing)
print("Use isnan function store 0")
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit data[np.isnan(data)] = 0
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit np.copyto(data, 0, where=np.isnan(data))
print("Use missing list store np.nan")
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit data[missing] = np.nan
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit data[wheremiss] = np.nan
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit np.copyto(data, np.nan, where=missing)
print("Use isnan function store np.nan")
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit data[np.isnan(data)] = np.nan
data[data==0] = np.nan
%timeit np.copyto(data, np.nan, where=np.isnan(data))
```

And I got the following output (I have taken the liberty to add numbers to the timing lines, so that I can refer to them later):

```
3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 22:01:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
numpy version 1.17.1
01. 30 µs ± 2.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
02. 219 µs ± 24.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Use missing list store 0
03. 339 µs ± 23.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
04. 26 µs ± 1.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
05. 287 µs ± 26.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Use isnan function store 0
06. 38.5 µs ± 2.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
07. 43.8 µs ± 4.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Use missing list store np.nan
08. 328 µs ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
09. 24.8 µs ± 2.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
10. 322 µs ± 30 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Use isnan function store np.nan
11. 356 µs ± 31.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
12. 300 µs ± 4.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So here is the first question. Why would it take nearly 10 times longer to store a `np.nan` than to store a 0? (compare lines 6 and 7 vs. lines 11 and 12)

Why would it take much longer to use a stored list of `missing` as compared to recomputing the missing values using the `isnan` function? (compare lines 3 and 5 vs. 6 and 7)

This is just for curiosity. I can see that the fastest way is to use `np.where` to get a list of indices (because I have only 10% missing). But if I had many more, things might not be so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're not measuring what you think you are!  you're mutating your `data` while doing the test, and `timeit` runs the test multiple times.  thus additional runs are running on changed data.  when you change the value to `0` the next time you run `isnan` you get nothing back and assignment is basically a no-op.  while when you're assigning `nan` this causes more work to be done in the next iteration.

your question about when to use `np.where` vs leaving it as an array of `bool`s is a bit more difficult.  it would involve the relative sizes of the different datatypes (e.g. `bool` is 1 byte, `int64` is 8 bytes), the proportion of values that are selected, how well the distribution matches up to the CPU/memory subsystem's optimisations (e.g. are they mostly in one block vs. uniformly distributed), the relative cost of doing `np.where` vs how many times the result will be reused, and other things I can't think of right now.

for other users, it might be worth pointing out that [RAM latency (i.e. speed) is >100 times slower than L1 cache](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), so keeping memory access predictable is important to maximize cache utilisation